# GSuite user over storage quota - but numbers are below quota

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Attached is a screenshot of what I see for a specific user.
She is complaining of not receiving emails anymore so I guess it's true.

But I am having a hard time understanding, how can she be "over" quota if both numbers are below 100%?

[image]

Comment: I got it. It seems the admin view does not show everything. On her account it also shows 4.5GB in Google Photos

Comment: So the image you posted is *your* view of her account and not *her* view of her account.

Comment: Yes it is what I see in the administrative dashboard

Answer (score 2):

Had this very issue today - it seems, per G Suite support, that storage used by Google Photos is NOT shown at the admin console.

One can find this info under REPORTS > User Reports > Accounts however.

Answer (score 1):

**Possibility**:

**Could it be that she uses Gmail as a collect address form another email?**

If that is the case it could be that **her other email box is full** and emails are not delivered to that address resulting to only those emails not delivered to Gmail (or anywhere else for that matter).

**Debug**:

- Ask her to send **you** an email and reply to it and see if she receives it.
- Ask her to send an email to herself like:
  From: hermail@gmail.com
  To: hermail+test@gmail.com

**Links with possible solutions to your issue**
Keep in mind that the Storage on Legacy edition is  15 GB for each user on your Free Edition

- [Storage settings](https://www.google.com/settings/storage)
- [Clear Google Drive space & increase storage](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6374270)
- [Drive storage FAQ for admins](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9214707)
- [Let users buy more Drive storage](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047457)
- [Change a user’s license to a different subscription](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1727172)
- [Use a group as a collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430)
- [Restore a suspended Gmail account](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2789146)

Comment: She is not using Gmail to collect other emails. I sent her an email, and received a quota error.

Comment: Please check the updated answer